# Matrix equations in MatLab

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab, matrix-equations

Do you by any chance know if I can solve matrix equations like this: $$\left ( B^{-1}X-A \right )^{-1}A^{-1}=I$$ in MatLab? Considering $A$ and $B$ are given and I need $X$.

I found how to do it for $AX=B$ but it's not helpful to me.

Namely  I need a quick way to check if my calculations are okay because solutions are not provided in textbook.

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not solve for $X$? You'll get $X = B(A+A^{-1})$, which I'm sure you can do in Matlab.

Comment: I can do it now because I checked with you that solving for X is correct :D Now it's just a calculation. I was thinking maybe there's a way to do it by giving the equation in its implicit form to MatLab.

Comment: Technically you could generate a matrix of symbolic elements using the symbolic math toolbox and solve it using that, but symbolic math is many orders of magnitude slower than the direct calculation.